# Material 2 md-chip Not Responsing to color Attribute

Tags: angular, angular-material2, md-chip

I can't seem to get my chip to respond to my color selection and I don't know why.

```
<md-chip-list>
   <md-chip selected="true" color="primary">Test</md-chip>
</md-chip-list>
```

It shows up but its always gray. My `primary` color has always worked for other components. I have tried `secondary` and `accent` as well with no change.

Here is what I see in the console looking at the elements:
[image]

Here are my dependencies in package.json:
[image]

Comment: Might you have conflicting CSS? If you inspect the md-chip with chrome console, there should be background-color set, you can inspect chips in the documentation page for reference: https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview

Comment: Just to verify you are trying to change the background color correct?

Comment: Yes. The background. I looked at the console and I see this class
    .mat-chip:not(.mat-basic-chip) {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    }

If I override this in the component CSS it works. But if I use the standard color assignment in HTML the chip is always gray.

Comment: Have you added material theme.?

Comment: @Faisal Yes. As indicated in the question, all of my other components respond to the `color` attribute properly

Comment: @Hodglem if you inspect the dom, does the chip have the class `mat-chip-selected`?

Comment: @WillHowell Class is `class=mat-chip mat-primary`. I will post a picture of what I see in the elements in the op.

Comment: @Hodglem that explains it, the `mat-chip-selected` class provides the color. I don't know why that class wouldn't be getting applied. Also note that `aria-selected` is false in your element too...

Comment: @Hodglem Angular and Material versions?

Comment: @WillHowell Angular 4.4.3 and the url https://github.com/angular/material2-builds.git is set to get the latest Material 2. I'll post a picture of my package.json dependencies in op.

Comment: Looks like a bug! Can you create an issue for it? Use this plunker as a reproduction: http://plnkr.co/edit/fwvENkXwj8lDv36JRLvq?p=preview

Comment: Sure. Will do. Thanks @WillHowell